# Xcode gives an error on OpenCL basic example in gclExecKernelAPPLE

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel, opencl

I am trying OpenCL in Xcode and used the basic example provided by Apple, here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/ExampleHelloWorld/Example_HelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH112-SW2

It works fine, but when i change the NUM-VALUES to other number it returns an error code -54 in gclExecKernelAPPLE. What this error means?
I am using XCode 5 and OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error -54 means: `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`

Wich is a logical error, since you change the global work size but maintained the local size as is. This probably leads to work group size that is non an integer divisor of the global size, producing that error.

That is a very simple and basic error. I recommend you to read carefully the OpenCL standard first. Since you will not learn at all if you don't read it first.

Comment: Given that the sample is a "hello world" style tutorial, I wouldn't expect the op to have memorized the entire OpenCL spec quite yet.